# Delete Configurable rather than Simple product on checkout_cart_product_add_before event

Tags: magento2

Im using

```
checkout_cart_product_add_before
```

observer event to call a class that removes the product from the card and re-adds it. I required this because i needed the quantity to equal what was entered in the qty text box rather than add it to the total (eg if cart qty was 10, and i put 5 in the qty box the default Magento2 functionality would make the quantity in the cart 15 - my script makes it 5)

The issue is it is only working for simple products, when it comes to configurable products (a product that might have 2 color swatches black and green) it is removing the whole product and re-adding the new configarable (for example if i have qty 5 of blue shirt, i add qty 8 of green shirt it removes the blue shirt completly and adds the green shirt.

I have wrapped my script in if not configurable to stop this happening but does anyone know how i can edit this script to remove the configurable id rather than the simple?

```
namespace XX\XX\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;


class DeleteAndReAddFromCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;
    protected $_cart;
    /** @var CheckoutSession */
    protected $checkoutSession;
    
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, cart $cart, CheckoutSession $checkoutSession)
    {
        $this->_cart           = $cart;
        $this->request         = $request;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {     
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        
        $productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
        $prodtype = $observer->getProduct()->getTypeId(); //is configarable or simple
        
        $items     = $this->_cart->getItems();
        $itemCount = count($items);
        if ($itemCount > 0) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {

                if ($prodtype != 'configurable') {
                    if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId) {
                        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                        $item->isDeleted(true);
                        $this->_cart->save();
                    }
            }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```